# Why does it matter even if nobody else will?

Tags: ethics

Gandhi said that **Whatever you do in life will be insignificant, but it's very important that you do it because nobody else will.** Also quoted in  [Remember Me](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1403981/quotes).

Why does it matter even if nobody else will?

Comment: Because only the good will is good in itself and the categorical imperative commands regardless of outer circumstances, like, for example, your fellow men's opinion or actions (says e.g. Kant).

Comment: Gandhi was a Hindu - so I think it would be useful to answer in terms of his own worldview. Having said that he came into contact with Christianity in England as a student, and in South Africa as a barrister. From what I recall in his auto-biography he was too taken by Christianity itself, but he did admire the personality and ethics of Christ.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I am unable to grasp why being Hindu makes his view as "own worldview" it is always a view of persons own worldview. I have too read his autobiography but couldn't see much of the reference to being influenced by Christianity(please quote some example). By the way Jesus had an admirable personality or many good things, making Christianity the biggest religion.

Comment: @iphigenie I couldn't get your example how is the fellow men's opinion or action are good.....

Comment: @mudBorn: I can't say I understand your critique - can you explain a little further. I didn't say he was hugely influenced by Christainity - I said he came into *contact* wit it, and he *admired* Christs character. Have a look at the autobiography again - its in the section when he's iin South Africa, and being bored with tea at the houses of genteel christians.

Answer (score 2):

Note: he says "*because* nobody else will" -- although insignificant in comparison to the wide world, your actions are significant/special because of their uniqueness: no one else can/will do what you decide to do.

Comment: in todays world there are many managers and leader who inspire others to do what they want to do or in corporate world achieve the goals of company. Also I disagree how could the actions be insignificant in world view if internet wouldn't have been here this question have not being posted and u answered...and same with all the man-made things